# AngularJS website sample failing to execute (version 1.2.0)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the sample (from Angular official site):

```
angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']).
  value('fbURL', 'https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/').
  factory('Projects', function(angularFireCollection, fbURL) {
    return angularFireCollection(fbURL);
  }).
  config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {controller:ListCtrl, templateUrl:'list.html'}).
      when('/edit/:projectId', {controller:EditCtrl, templateUrl:'detail.html'}).
      when('/new', {controller:CreateCtrl, templateUrl:'detail.html'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
  });

function ListCtrl($scope, Projects) {
  $scope.projects = Projects;
}

function CreateCtrl($scope, $location, $timeout, Projects) {
  $scope.save = function() {
    Projects.add($scope.project, function() {
      $timeout(function() { $location.path('/'); });
    });
  }
}

function EditCtrl($scope, $location, $routeParams, angularFire, fbURL) {
  angularFire(fbURL + $routeParams.projectId, $scope, 'remote', {}).
  then(function() {
    $scope.project = angular.copy($scope.remote);
    $scope.project.$id = $routeParams.projectId;
    $scope.isClean = function() {
      return angular.equals($scope.remote, $scope.project);
    }
    $scope.destroy = function() {
      $scope.remote = null;
      $location.path('/');
    };
    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.remote = angular.copy($scope.project);
      $location.path('/');
    };
  });
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/TE2WR/

Firefox console shows:

> [01:45:20.760] Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/modulerr?p0=project&p1=%5B%24injector%[...]

What's going on?

## Edit:

My HTML scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="http://firebase.github.io/angularFire/angularFire.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle is blank.

Comment: Thank you... I've updated it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to include ngRoute and firebase scripts so that they are available to inject as dependencies.

For example, include ngRoute like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>

angular.module('project', ['ngRoute']).
  config(function($routeProvider) {

  });
```

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos as I said, ngRoute isn't available to be injected. Give me a moment and I'll show you.

Comment: Now the error has changed: `[02:33:14.104] "Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <- ngViewDirective
yb/m.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:29 [...]`

Comment: Also: `[02:33:14.104] "Error: Circular dependency: ngViewDirective
c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:27[...]`

Comment: See this: http://jsbin.com/EZObAZe/1/edit Your example is overly complex. It's unreasonable to debug that way. Add in relevant code piece by piece until you find a problem, and preferably isolate that problem. You're just trying to use things you haven't properly setup.

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code and the error is the same as the original on. I'm running in on localhost with Apache.

Comment: Do you mean that you used my code and ONLY my code? @HenriqueBarcelos

Comment: `[07:51:01.699] Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/modulerr?p0=project[...]` Pay attention to the error, it looks like it's having a problem injecting the module `project` that I'm creating...

Comment: If I remove the value of the `ng-app` atribute and let it be blank, the error is gone, but, of course, nothing is working...

Comment: For some reason, your solution worked today for me... Maybe due some caching issue it wasn't working... Thank you for your help and sorry for being stubborn about this...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos no problem!! I'm glad you have everything worked out.

Answer (score 2):

You missed angular-route.js and firebase.js and angularfire.js in jsfiddle.

This would work

```
</style> <!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue: http://goo.gl/BUfGZ --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/firebase/angularFire/master/angularfire.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<style>
```

Comment: Do you not realize my answer says the same thing? Just because you have the same problem doesn't mean it's ok to repeat my answer.